# TabBar Controller Selection color

Tags: indexing, tabs, tabbar, selected

Is there any one who has implemented for the TabBar Controller application in which on selection of tab item it shows different colour other than gray and blue color?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can change the selected button color with:

```
self.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

and the tabbar background color with:

```
self.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

but only iOS 5.0

Comment: any alternate way for <ios5.0?

Answer (score 1):

As I already posted here: [Change tab bar tint color on iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795117/change-tab-bar-tint-color-ios-7/19098819#19098819)

There is an much easier way to do this.

Just open the file inspector and select a "global tint".

You can also set an app’s tint color in Interface Builder. The Global Tint menu in the Interface Builder Document section of the File inspector lets you open the Colors window or choose a specific color.

Also see:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarC = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"5.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
    tabBarC.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Remember, only with iOS5+.

Comment: any alternate way for <ios5.0?