# Creating a custom Tab Bar Controller, Change the Background

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift2, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

Im currently lay-outing a tab bar controller but I'm having a hard time to make this one in story board, i want a custom background form tab bar and changes when it is active

[image]

I have tried using tab bar controller and use image assets and still nothing happen its just a gray in color, i tried to layout the tab bar in a view controller however i dont know what will i do next.

[image]

I would really appreciate if someone can help me thanks! :D

Comment: please paste the code also what you tried???

Comment: I haven't try to code it yet, I just layout it on the storyboard

Comment: you ca change the tint colour of perticular tap on tabbar.please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795117/change-tab-bar-tint-color-on-ios-7

Comment: Hello Im using Swift 2.0, Is there any swift code?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html